# Customising instantiation of WCF web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, testing

I have a WCF RESTful service that I want to integration test so need to create an instance of the service locally within the test with a reference to a client channel that I can call. I can do this, however the code I'm using will only call the Services default parameterless constructor as below

```
_serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(UserService), baseAddress);
var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Interface.IUserService), binding, address.Uri);            
_serviceHost.Open();
```

In my UserService class, I want to inject a dependency into it for the data repository, as so

```
  public UserService(IUserDataRepository userRepository)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }
```

How can I adapt the first lot of code so that I can create and self host my WCF REST service with an IDataRepository object that I create (Mock) in the test class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you can use the same approach as you have for production environment. I might be wrong but you must already have your custom ServiceHost and ServiceHostFactory. If not please take a look at this article [Using Instance Provider and ServiceHostFactory to Construct the Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You want to read through steps steps 1-3. You will need to derive from WebServiceHost to implement your own one. Then your code will look like that:

```
_serviceHost = new YourCustomServiceHost(typeof(UserService), baseAddress);
```

Hope it helps!